# AutoHotKey if clipboard contains in array value

Tags: autohotkey

I am making a script for validating wallet cryptocurrency.
so whenever I copy the address wallet and then I run the script. if the address wallet same as the array value, it will show `msgbox` that give information about the wallet name. if not it will show `n/a`.

but I have some problems, where the `msgbox` shows based many numbers of the array

here is my code

```
^q::
walletAddr := Object("wallet1", "0x01415e36ce36d07229abf8b0435669088319f656", "wallet2", "0x9d6fb140607e1727c1373624a97ba681ef54f5bk", "wallet3", "0x660f01a47efd305862bc598cad44d1966b376d67")
found := 0
for k, v in walletAddr
    if ( clipboard == v ) {
        MsgBox % k
        found := 1
    }
if !found
    MsgBox, n/a
return
```

and I figure out that this problem isn't from the script. but from the array value.
I try to change the value to a simple word and it works perfectly

```
walletAddr := Object("wallet1", 0xFF0000, "wallet2", 0x0000FF,"wallet3", 0x00FF00)
```

I have no clue where the problems come from. maybe it's because of length value, value typedata, or others.

can someone help me figure out my problem? thank you

Answer (score 0):

i found tricky way to make it work :D
just add string text ( i use = "wallet_" ) before value and before clipboard.